# why kotlin lambda decompiled to java code is (Function0)null.INSTANCE

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

when I declare a property in a class as following:

```
class xx{
    var b:()->Boolean={false}
}
```

and then decompiled as following:

```
......

public xxx() {
    this.b = (Function0)null.INSTANCE;
}

......
```

what does the (Function0)null.INSTANCE stand for?
I think it will be :

```
this.b= new Function0() {
        public final Object invoke() {
                 return false;
         }
};
```

but it doesn't ,why?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly because your decompiler is bad at decompiling.

Comment: Which decompiler did you use? Can you also post the imports.

Comment: AndroidStudio built in:Tools->Kotlin->Show Kotlin Bytecode->Decompile

Answer (score 6):

Decompiler not showing the correct result: e.g. when doing it with JD-GUI, you get:

```
final class xx$b$1 extends Lambda implements kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<Boolean> { 
  public final boolean invoke() { return false; }

  public static final 1 INSTANCE = new 1();
  xx$b$1()
  {
    super(0);
  }
}


public final class xx { 
  // ... getter and setter
  private Function0<Boolean> b = (Function0)xx.b.1.INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Hi @xzwhappy, if this is the solution, please just mark this answer as such. thx